# HTA - How to close HTA after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, hta

Completely new with HTA. I have HTML page that allows user to submit password request for one of our applications. This works all fine until machine was upgrade to Windows 10, and I no longer have rights to get Object email and user account. Good news it works if I save file as HTA.
But Once form is submitted, it closed the form on javascript bit, and the form is reloaded. 
How to:
On Submit button run a JavaScript code and then close HTA?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Form</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION>
    <body oncontextmenu="return false"  onload='setFocusToTextBox()'>

    <h1><strong>Test Password reset</strong></h1>
    </head>
    <script Language="VBScript">

    Option Explicit

    Sub Window_Onload

       window.resizeTo 640, 480
       dataarea.innerhtml = "<form  name=""MyForm"" autocomplete=""off"" onsubmit=""WriteFile()"">" & _
       "<p>" & _
       "<h4>FDM Username:" & _ 
       "<input type=""text"" id=""uname"" placeholder=""Username (eg: SMITHA)"" required/></h4>" & _
       "<center><h5>(eg: WHITEP)</h5></center>" & _
       "<br>" & _
       "<h4><input class=""button""  name=""button"" type=""submit"" value=""Submit Request"" id=""SubBtn"" onclick=""changeSubmit();""/></h4>" & _
       "</p>" & _
       "</form>"      



     end sub

     Sub CloseWin
       Self.Close()
       Window.Close()
      End Sub
     </script>

     <span id=DataArea></span>

    <script language="javascript">

    function WriteFile() {

       var getResult = confirm("Rquest submitted, HERE IS THE PROBLEM WHEN CLICK OK, IT RELOAD THE FORM IN A NEW SCREEN.");
      CloseWin();
    }

    function changeSubmit() {
        document.getElementById("SubBtn").value="Submitted"; 

     }

    function setFocusToTextBox(){
        document.getElementById("uname").focus();
    }

     </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of HTAs.

The short answer is that you can simply call closeWin() (your vbscript sub with the brackets) from your javascript function.

While testing your code I got some errors because the html parts that call functins onsubmit and onclick you need to specify the language in the tag

```
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" language="javascript"/>
```

Also, the most impotant thing you need to know about HTA files is how to set the version of Internet Explorer the file will use.  By default it's 7 I think so you'll find that more recent HTML like "placeholder" will not work.  You can change this with a meta tag (see below).  Don't go above 10 if you want vbscript to work.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=10" />
```

** UPDATE **

I had a look at your updated code and it is the form sumission that is opening the browser.  You really don't need the form to submit or even to have the text box and button contained within a form.

I changed your onload sub and added the focus code to it as I was getting an error because the Javascript was running before the VBScript and couldn't set the focus.  I took out the function setFocusToTextBox()

The only thing that is missing is that the request is not processed automatically when the user presses ENTER so they have to press the button.  There is a way around that but it's not really a big issue.

```
Sub Window_Onload

   window.resizeTo 640, 480
   dataarea.innerhtml = "" & _
   "<p>" & _
   "<h4>FDM Username:" & _ 
   "<input type=""text"" id=""uname"" placeholder=""Username (eg: SMITHA)"" required/></h4>" & _
   "<center><h5>(eg: WHITEP)</h5></center>" & _
   "<br>" & _
   "<h4><input class=""button""  name=""button"" type=""button"" value=""Submit Request"" id=""SubBtn"" onclick=""WriteFile()""/></h4>" & _
   "</p>"     

document.getElementById("uname").focus()

 end sub
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, many thanks for you assistance. Unfortunately I am still not able to close the screen without reloading a new TAB with the page.

Comment: Are you submitting the for to a web/intranet address?  It sounds like the hta is navigating to a new page and that's why the code to close is not running.  You could try putting the form in an iframe.

Comment: when form is submitted, a javascript create a text file and display the message "File Submitted" and then it should exit the HTA. I gonna try to place a simple code on here.

Comment: if you're not submitting the form to a url then you can change the button to onclick instead of onsubmit so that it does not navigate away from the hta code.

Comment: Wonderful.  It worked gracefully.  I added <HTA: elements> to display ICON="images/favicon.ico" which displays when running on the server, but it doesn't display when running from the shortcut. I really appreciate your assistance.